# Not able to apply material to a Animation Node target

Tags: materials, animation-nodes

i watched Curtis Holts Animation Nodes tutorial and started making a drone glitch effect project with it , so the target is to make a plan with a simple flooring texture and displacements , some walls , a drone model parented to a empty, The animation nodes will be taking the mesh from the plane which is the flooring and generating a target using the object output and mesh input. The floor which is just a subdivided plane has problems with materials. **When i Unwrap the mesh , it works fine but when i move the empty which changes the geometry of the plane , the mesh returns to a brown texture without the proper flooring texture**

**Original Plane**

[image]

**Target Plane**

[image]

My Uvs are proper , the normals are not flipped....

Comment: UV coordinate space without a UVMap will create the problem you are seeing. Can't see the coodinate space your texture coordinate node is using, uv, generated.. Did you unwrap the plane?

Comment: Ohh , Unwrapped it again and it worked , idk what was happening i did unwrap , by the way , write the awnsere

Comment: @Timaroberts is till have a problem , ,whenever i unwrap , it becomes normal , but when i move the empty which is the point falloff for the animation node  , in other words , the empty causes some changes in the geometry of the plane , the plan returns to the plane brown color and looses the desired floor texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [*unwrap*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/introduction.html#workflow) your object.

When you don't unwrap your object and use UV coordinates in the [texture coordinate node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#texture-coordinate-node), Blender will make some assumptions about the material, which is why you see the generic looking color that you see.

Unwrap the plane to add a UVMap to the object, and that will solve the problem:

[image]

Comment: problem is solved but i mad an edit to my question , have a look at that..........